# What does the method `getLinkTemplate` do in an entity type?

Tags: 8, routes

I am trying to debug the Access by Entity module, and it isn't generating new routes that it should be doing in its RouteSubscriber.

This line here:

`if ($access_load = $entity_type->getLinkTemplate('access-entity')) {`

It is always FALSE. What is `getLinkTemplate` method for? [I checked the doc page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityTypeInterface.php/function/EntityTypeInterface%3A%3AgetLinkTemplates/8.2.x), but didn't come away with a lot of information and I have not seen this used before today (outside core).

Comment: Link template is just a route path for an operation on the entity. Like edit form, add form, delete form or canonical page. That function only returns the route path so that you can build a link out of it without loading the full route. Have a look at node entity definition and the "links" key is what I'm talking about.

Comment: This looks buggy, unless I am unaware of some auto-magic. It seems as if an explicit call like e.g. `setLinkTemplate('access-entity', 'node/{node}/access-entity}')` is missing. Some modules (e.g. forum) do this in a 'hook_entity_type_build' implementation.